# Rails create record with column of type 'Date'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, date, datetime

I have a class named record which have these columns:

```
'ID' INT, 
'RECORD' VARCHAR2(50),
'CREATED_AT' DATE,
'UPDATED_AT' DATE,
'MANUAL_UPDATE' DATE
```

I want to insert new record with the following code:

```
Record.new(ID: '1', RECORD: 'Foo', MANUAL_UPDATE: '20150110122356')
```

New record will be created but inside the `MANUAL_UPDATE` column, the values become Nil.

I want to create a record with provided string in the format of `'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`. How do I do that?

More information on the Database's structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ZMNS_TEST.SAVED_ITEMS
(
  ID                             INT NOT NULL,
  RECORD                         VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  CREATED_AT                     DATE NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_AT                     DATE NOT NULL,
  MANUAL_UPDATE                  DATE,
)
```

Comment: where is `MANUAL_UPDATE` column defined? Can you share your db migration file?

Comment: @shivam sorry about that. The 'SHUSEI_DATETIME' is actually the 'MANUAL_UPDATE' column I mentioned. I changed the name when writting this question since it's naming is in Japanese Language.

Comment: are you editing the database directly or running `db:migrate` to create tables?

Comment: @shivam I'm running db:migrate. I'm really sorry to tell you that after some trial and error, the methods you posted work! It seemed that I forgot the attr_accessible setting for "MANUAL_UPDATE". It worked now. :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert a `String` (timestamp) to a `Date` column and therefore you're getting `nil`. You have two options:

1> Update proper date as in:

```
Record.new(ID: '1', RECORD: 'Foo', MANUAL_UPDATE: Date.today)
```

2> Convert your timestamp to date and then update:

```
date = Date.strptime("20150110122356",'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
#=> Sat, 10 Jan 2015
Record.new(ID: '1', RECORD: 'Foo', MANUAL_UPDATE: date)
```

Comment: I tried both of your methods, both returned MANUAL_UPDATE with nil. It is weird that even Date.today didn't got inserted into the record.

Answer (score 0):

Try the method below

```
Date.strptime('20150110122356', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

Record.new(ID: '1', RECORD: 'Foo', MANUAL_UPDATE: Date.strptime('20150110122356', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
```